# Advantage of a statistical test with a low power

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Let's say we have two statistical methods, M1 and M2:

- We state the null hyp: The effect of something is 0
- M1 has less power than M2 (harder to reject a false null, so M1 more often makes type II errors)

Is the following interpretation correct?:

When we reject the null by applying method M1 because of a very tiny p-value, we all else equal end up having stronger evidence for the presence of an effect compared to if we had rejected the null by applying method M2 due to a low p-value.

Comment: This is what Gelman calls the “What does not kill my statistical significance makes it stronger” fallacy: https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2017/02/06/not-kill-statistical-significance-makes-stronger-fallacy/

Comment: But what if I actually don't suffer from a small sample problem? My N=64, and I don't see noise as a problem since I'm using rank-based methods. Is it still a fallacy?